# SUM IF not working in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, formula

I have this table

```
price   product
25  apple
10  bananas
15  apple
30  oranges
45  oranges
5   bananas

In cell A10==SUM(IF((B2:B7="apple"),A2:A7,0))        <--- this does not work #VALUE! error

but this works A9==SUMIF(B2:B7,"=apple",A2:A7)      <--- works
```

What am I doing wrong. The syntax seem to be correct according to [Microsoft site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275165)

> =SUM(IF((A2:A9="A")+(A2:A9="B"),B2:B9,0))

I need to make nested if work because I have more than one criteria for sum.

Comment: Did you, as per the Microsoft page you linked to, enter the formula with ctrl-shift-Enter to make it an "array formula"?

Comment: Do you enter it as an array formula by pressing ctrl+shift+enter?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan oops, it worked. lol

Comment: ok I have another question. I'll modify the question. I need to enter this formula programatically in C#, will I be able to do this? Coz Ctrl_Shift+Enter required?

Comment: You can use a non-array SUMIF for multiple criteria, e.g. `=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A9,{"A","B"},B2:B9))`

Comment: @barryhoudini sumif does not work for multiple criteria or does it? It will be better for my purpose

Comment: figured it out, the solution is use `sumproduct`

Comment: you can also use SUMIFS this will take multiple criteria

Comment: Feel free to answer this question so I can accept answer. Garath and @Aptem your comments were helpful. The answer must be written in proper format addressing both the issue that I had. Otherwise I will write my own answer.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter are you threatening us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "else" clause of your IF is a zero, you don't need the IF.

```
=SUM(((A2:A9="A")+(A2:A9="B"))*(B2:B9))
```

entered with control+shift+enter.  Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A9="A")+(A2:A9="B"))*(B2:B9))
```

entered normally.  I don't know why MS shows it the way they do.